# Postgres query cannot find rows based on column value

Tags: sql, postgresql, quoted-identifier

I want to select rows based on a column value. I know for a fact the column value exists. The first query returns 100 rows from the `listing` table. The second query, which looks for `listings.OriginatingSystemName` = 'mfrmls` returns nothing. Why?

(Removing the quotes or using double quotes does not work).

I am using pgAdmin4 to run these queries.

first query:

```
select * from listing limit 100;
```

second query:

```
select * from listing where 'listing.OriginatingSystemName' = 'mfrmls'
```

This produces a 'column does not exist' error:

```
select * from listing where OriginatingSystemName = 'mfrmls'
```

Comment: Please avoid posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data or code, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). See the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Have you tried the where clause "OriginatingSystemName" like '%mfrmls%' to see if there may be spaces in column values?

Comment: I tried running 
SELECT * FROM listings WHERE 'OriginatingSystemName' = '%mfrmls%';

but no luck

Comment: I updated the question to remove the code images per Stu comment

Comment: Single quotes are for string constants, not for column (or table) names.

Answer (score 4):

The correct syntax is to just write the column name in your WHERE statement:

```
SELECT * FROM listings WHERE "OriginatingSystemName" = 'mfrmls';
```

To elaborate further:

What your original query is doing is selecting every row in the listings table where the text string 'listings.OriginatingSystemName' is equal to this other text string 'mfrmls'. It is not actually grabbing the value from the column you want. No row in the table satisfies your where statement because your where statement is always false. Therefore, no rows are returned but the query was a success.

We need to implement the double quotes when dealing with case-sensitive identifiers. Here is some helpful [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

Comment: Your solution produces the following: `ERROR: column "originatingsystemname" does not exist` Putting quote marks around the column also does not work.

Comment: Sorry about that. Try wrapping your column name in double quotes. "OriginatingSystemName". Double quotes are used for case senstive identifiers. I'll correct the answer for you